# Many-To-Many Column not found Issue in Subfield relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I am using Laravel BackPack Pro and I am receiving an error when trying to save a relationship in a subfield.

My Model structure:

Event Model 1-n Badge n-m Packages

The error I receive when trying to save.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'packages' in 'field list' 
update `badges` set `packages` = ["1"], `badges`.`updated_at` = 2022-06-28 22:40:36 where `id
```

The following is my configuration in my EventCrudController. The Idea is to attach different Badges to an event and only make it available to certain badges.

```
   CRUD::field('badges')
        ->type('relationship')
        ->subfields([
            [   // relationship
                'name' => 'packages', // the method on your model that defines the relationship
                'type' => "relationship",

                // OPTIONALS:
                // 'label' => "Category",
                // 'attribute' => "title", // attribute on model that is shown to user
                // 'placeholder' => "Select a category", // placeholder for the select2 input
            ],
        ]);
```

The weird thing is, that using laravel tinker I can successfully attach any packages. And it displays correctly in the admin but it does not let me save anything. I am unsure if this is a bug or just me configuring it wrongly.

```
class Badge extends Model
{
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;

public $guarded = [];

public function packages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Package::class,'badge_package');
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUze9.png)

Comment: Hello there. I've just tested the scenario you described and I was able to make it work https://recordit.co/SuEWKUAAoR Can you tell me what version are you running with: `php artisan backpack:version` ? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/4142 it is currently not supported.